# Validate $regex on field that might not exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
name: { 
  $regex: /^.{0,200}$/ 
}
```

Can this kind of validation be done with MongoDB document validation if name field isn't guaranteed to exist? Because now I get validation error if that name field doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question and the comment, you would want to define the validation in your collection so that you will validate the name field against the regex if exists. To achieve this add $exists false to your validator like this.

```
db.createCollection( "contacts",
{ validator: { $or:
  [
     { name: { $exists: false} },
     { name: { $regex: /^.{0,200}$/ } }
  ]
}
} )
```

If you want to allow something like this

```
{
   name:  null
}
```

You would also add [$ne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) to your validation

```
 $ne: null
```

Does this help?

Comment: Yeah, that's it, thank you very much! Can't believe how stupid I was that I didn't realize you can place more than one rule for one field.. :D

Answer (score 0):

Use $exists on your query
Example:

```
db.inventory.find( { name: { $exists: true, $regex: /^.{0,200}$/  } } )
```

For more about $exist you can refer at below link

[Link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)

Hope this may solve your issue

Comment: I'm not trying to query anything but use MongoDB validator. And using $exists means I want that field either to always exist or not exist, when the case is that I don't care whether that field exists when creating or updating files. I just want to ensure its length isn't more than 200